# Why doesn't countif returning correct results?

Tags: excel, countif

I am attempting to count different values in an Excel column, whose values are taken from another sheet in the same file.
i.e. the value of D2 is "=VLOOKUP(A2, Journals!B:E, 2, FALSE)", which returns 3.057.
I have written the following functions:

```
=COUNTIF($D$2:$D$201, ">10")
=COUNTIFS($D$2:$D$201, "<10",$D$2:$D$201, ">=5")
=COUNTIFS($D$2:$D$201, ">=1",$D$2:$D$201, "<5")
=COUNTIF($D$2:$D$201, "<1")
=COUNTIF($D$1:$D$201, #N/A)
```

The total count should be 200 values, but I am only counting 53 for an unknown reason, and different values for each cell.
For example, there are 26 values larger than 10, but I get 7 (if I change the value to >10* I get 133, which is totally bizarre).

Does anyone know why that is?

Here is the data:

```
3.057
5.228
0.879
9.423
8.490
4.587
8.405
5.008
9.202
11.329
5.992
37.369
2.352
0.821
6.661
4.409
38.138
2.400
6.585
3.634
18.393
3.040
4.391
2.934
3.154
13.334
5.463
2.561
3.920
3.052
4.534
3.043
13.779
2.134
7.760
4.258
6.975
5.531
3.148
8.005
2.332
7.870
4.575
44.002
2.787
5.924
1.737
1.053
8.303
3.544
4.820
4.197
6.059
6.035
3.867
13.038
2.466
3.794
4.426
11.351
9.269
1.206
3.784
3.632
2.989
5.089
2.043
2.948
2.914
2.118
#N/A
5.621
5.912
1.991
4.638
7.760
4.706
2.587
8.580
4.317
10.794
5.181
7.003
21.407
2.341
3.559
20.982
11.847
5.812
5.766
5.985
28.710
2.049
2.291
4.358
5.538
3.912
17.759
2.042
1.387
3.859
3.570
8.166
4.681
1.627
5.771
4.919
2.320
3.635
1.847
1.434
12.384
1.858
4.487
2.776
3.169
0.841
4.037
14.921
2.796
10.125
4.314
3.849
7.932
3.093
5.101
2.319
1.413
6.280
1.923
5.677
#N/A
4.165
1.833
3.408
2.183
5.557
1.542
2.382
3.792
1.647
2.093
15.064
1.942
5.196
5.840
3.792
2.857
3.064
4.985
8.934
4.218
3.603
4.453
1.731
3.636
4.667
2.656
8.285
1.680
12.485
10.581
3.943
3.016
5.610
6.615
9.463
3.519
1.113
29.298
2.754
5.634
16.240
5.301
2.760
7.242
3.782
2.081
10.383
59.558
8.668
5.040
3.014
4.606
5.874
3.818
4.580
6.915
6.991
3.842
3.184
2.000
3.540
11.000
1.674
4.470
4.465
3.905
3.464
4.803
```

So far I have attempted playing with * to widen the range and copy-paste value to make sure the problem isn't somehow made by the values coming from a different sheet, but nothing works.
Also the column is defined as numbers with 3 digits after .

Comment: Using your first formula I got the correct count of 26 (for `>10`). The issue could be that some of the cells are not formatted as numbers and may be strings. You could use `Value()` to convert all of the strings to numbers to check, then run the `COUNTIF` formulas on the converted values

Comment: Thanx, but the column is all numbers with 3 digits after the ., except for those cells which are #N/A.

Comment: Ok, so following your advice @Jordan I have added another column, then used =value() to get the values of the cells, then calculated that column instead of D.
It worked, but it's not pretty. Is there a way to calculate the value directly in D, for example =value(vlookup())? Or must I have two separate columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, following Jordan's comment, the functions in D were changed to:
=value(vlookup())

This solved the issue and allowed the countif to work correctly.

I'm not sure why this worked and simply formatting the column to number didn't, but there you have it.

Thanx @Jordan

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your code and got
26
53
116
3
2

Are your numbers formatted as numbers? What about locale (decimal dot or comma)? Formula arg separator (comma or semicolon?)

```
=COUNTIF($D$2:D201; ">10")
=COUNTIFS($D$2:$D$201; "<10";$D$2:$D$201; ">=5")
```

Comment: They are formatted as numbers, yes.
When I try to use ; I get an error message that there was a problem with the formula.